# How to directly get input tables' statistics in HQL?

Tags: statistics, hive, size, hql, rows

This page [StatsDev - Apache Hive - Apache Software Foundation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/StatsDev) tells us we could get the following statistics once we get input tables & partitions information in Hive:

- Number of rows
- Number of files
- Size in Bytes

However, can we get those statistics through just an unparsed HQL directly? Or we could only get them after parsing input tables & partitions information from HQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keyword EXPLAIN is what I want: [LanguageManual Explain - Apache Hive - Apache Software Foundation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Explain)